# Why should we use string resources in the various android components - "android:text" property?

Tags: android, xml, string, resources

It gives a warning when we simply type in a string and not refer a string resource.

Why is this so ?

I mean shouldn't it be more efficient if the component simply puts in the text string then and there rather than having to search through dozens, probably 100s of strings in the XML string files ?

Why does eclipse insist on using string resource rather than a string ?

Answer (score 5):

Putting the strings in a string resource allows your app to support multiple languages (by having a string resource file for each language you want to support).

It also prevents duplication in the case where you use the same string multiple times. You simply define it once in a string resource and refer it where ever you need to use it. If you later need to change its value, you only change it in one location (the string resource file).

Answer (score 1):

- Using string resources is great for special characters, such as theta, that aren't able to be in double quotes in your XML due to encoding.
- Strings that need to be accessed multiple times throughout a project can be  modified at one source.
- It supports multiple languages.